# How to set percentwidth in updateDisplayList() in action script for ToggleButton Bar

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

We use "buttonWidth" property to set width of Individual button in Toggle Button Bar, but i need Individual button width in percentage, where i tried in As3 by extending toggle button to set percentWidth in updatDisplayList() method, but no use.
 that to i am not good in custom components help me out with an eg or suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for setting the individual button percentwidth in ToggleButtonBar

```
Button(myToggleButtonBar.getChildAt(0)).percentWidth = 10;
```

Similarly for other buttons you can set percent width.

Comment: @user1847180 If this answers the question, please make sure you mark the answer as correct. It will reward Sumit for helping and effectively close out the question in the system.